# How to get the file path in Azure app Service resource?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I am writing C# code and I am trying to put the relative path to a file containing SQL code and execute it programmatically.

My application is an Azure App Service resource.

How can I get the path of the file and where does it exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the files deployed with your project in the Azure console.
[image]

On the path D:\home\site\wwwroot you would find the same files as in the bin\Release\net6.0 folder.